# Active Directory Authentication is not working on IPAD(Safari browser)

Tags: jquery, ipad, safari, windows-authentication, ios7

my website has integrated active directory authentication, when some hit my website from Ipad safari browser, AD credential box appears, if user click cancel button then page stuck, nothing happen, it should redirected to 401 page, but it does not .

anyone can tell me, what is wrong with this?

Comment: On which server is your application hosted?  Is it IIS?  Can you try by removing `Negotiate` option from the providers list in IIS

Answer (score 2):

Looks like ios7 has broken windows authentication:

https://discussions.apple.com/message/23037716#23037716

There are a few workarounds:

1. Set safari to private browsing mode
2. Download chrome on ios7

Comment: And my client uses only safari.

Answer (score -1):

I fixed this on my servers in IIS 7.5 by changing the authentication from Windows Authentication to Basic Authentication for the site.  In IIS select the site, doubleclick the "Authentication" icon, then disable "Windows Authentication" and enable "Basic Authentication.

Comment: Your fix for this login flaw is to completely disable security ? Bad form @Rick Hawkes